# How can I stop seeing hidden files in the Midnight Commander?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, filenames, file-manager, mc, dot-files

The Midnight Commander is a very helpful tool when we're using only the text mode. But sometimes it bothers me that I have to see all the hidden files inside a folder (files that begin with ".").

I've tried to find how to do it changing some configurations by myself and then looking on the man page. But I didn't succeed.

Does anyone know how can I do it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Choose Options from the menu bar, then Panel options.
You have it right there, 5th option on the left column: "Show hidden files".

[image: Panel options screenshot highlighting the option to Show hidden files]

Answer (score 64):

or you can toggle it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> (Alt-period)

Answer (score 11):

You might also try to toggle hidden files with <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (escape + period), if <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> does NOT work.

This keyboard shortcut works on my Debian+xfce installation.

Note, that originally it is `M-.`, where M stands for <kbd>Meta</kbd> key.
You can find more (fascinating!) information about it in the @Gilles answer here: [What does m-tab mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/319815/60449)

If you still prefer to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> instead of <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> you have to enable something like `Meta Sends Escape` in Your terminal.

In `xterm`, for example, You can do it by holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while clicking and holding the left mouse button. That pops up a menu where You can select `Meta Sends Escape`.

Comment: On MacOs Monterey it is escaped followed by period. By that I mean press and release escape and then press period. If you hold escape and press period then it will have some strange effects if you do this two time in a row.

Comment: This should be the real answer! It is much quicker than fiddling with the menu options!