# What does m-tab mean?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I've encountered some man pages which say 'press m-tab to do '. I figured C-tab means ctrl+tab, but can't understand what does m-tab mean. Anybody knows what is it?

Comment: Essentially win+tab. M refers to the meta key. I'm sure somebody here can give you the history of that, but I can only tell you that it usually is mapped to the windows key or sometimes the alt key.

Comment: I guess it's the meta key. meta+tab
See http://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys

Comment: +1 While the meaning has been hinted already, there is a need for an answer that explains the discrepancy. I read that 'M-Tab' can also mean 'Shift-Tab' a.k.a. 'backtab'. I couldn't find any definite explanation for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`M` is short for Meta. In the 1970s and 1980s, keyboards on machines running Unix systems often had three modifier keys: <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd>. For this reason, most applications use these three names as modifiers. Then in the 1990s people used more an more PC keyboards, which had no key labeled <kbd>Meta</kbd> but had a key labeled <kbd>Alt</kbd>, so the key labeled <kbd>Alt</kbd> was configured to send the `Meta` modifier expected by applications. Thus, when an application has key bindings with the `Meta` modifier, use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

On classic-era keyboards, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd> were ubiquitous, but <kbd>Meta</kbd> wasn't. Furthermore, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd> had a well-defined effect on most [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters, but <kbd>Meta</kbd> didn't. To indicate <kbd>Meta</kbd>, some terminals set the upper bit of the characters, which wasn't used for anything else, but that interfered with 8-bit character sets used in countries with an alphabetic script that went beyond plain Latin letters, either with a different alphabet such as Cyrillic or with diacritics. So another encoding was often used: <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>*key*</kbd> was encoded as <kbd>Escape</kbd> followed by <kbd>*key*</kbd>. With applications running in a text terminal (text mode console or terminal emulator under a graphical interface), you can press <kbd>Escape</kbd> followed by the key to trigger a <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>*key*</kbd> shortcut.

For `M-tab`, it's likely that you'll need to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>, because most window manager intercept <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, since <kbd>Alt</kbd> is mapped to <kbd>Meta</kbd>) as a shortcut to switch between windows. A few terminals also send the same key sequence for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, but it depends on how the terminal emulator is configured.